# Show IDAPython prompt

Tags: ida, idapython

Subj hides itself on a mere <kbd>Escape</kbd> pressed in the input field. How to bring it back? I didn't find a way short of restarting IDA.

It's IDA 6.1 x32 & IDAPython v1.5.2.

Comment: Which IDA version and environment do you speaking about ? Couldn;t reproduce it at Windows 8.1/Ida Pro 64 version 6.8.